# How can i get WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID of all the instances of my azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can i get WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID of all the instances of my azure website. i have contributor role on resource group. For testing my website, i want to manually send request to every instance, and for that i need WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ARM API you can use for this:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{app}/instances?api-version=2016-08-01
```

This returns an array, where the `name` in each element is the instance ID.

You can also find a sample of calling this API via PowerShell [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/aba32e3a8fe60bc50044b1a5f316ff22661359f8/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L118-L123).

Comment: i have tried this solution, and it is showing below error "{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}" is it because i don't have access to management portal?

Comment: If you are having authentication issues talking to the ARM API, that is a separate question not related to this one. This is the answer once you are able to get passed authentication. Please open a separate question for the general AUTH part.